# On the right cancellation in localization of category. Is it necessary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, localization, functors, derived-categories

I recently faced the concept of derived category, introduced as localization of homotopy category. I tried to verify of the axioms and I stucked in the following: In the definition of multiplicative system I see that LMS3 of https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VB (Stacks Project) is required. This axiom is widely used in proving that the composition of two maps is well defined.

However, in my notes, I'm unable to prove (there's no proof of the fact there), just the following remark:

> In the literature one usually finds an additional axiom for
> multiplicative systems called the cancellation property. It was not
> used in the above construction; it is necessary when one wants to
> prove the stronger property that the Hom-sets in the category $S^{−1}C$
> arise as filtered direct limits of Hom-sets in $C$.

Beside not understanding this sentence, is it true that right cancellation can be omitted or required? If so, how one can prove that the composition is well defined?

Any help or clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite follow.  I don't think LMS3 is right cancellation, so what is the link?  The axioms from the stacks project allow you to build the localized category.  If you want that category to have *additional* properties (likely nicely colimited hom-sets), you'll need additional axioms.

Comment: @Randall In my definition of multiplicative system I don't have LMS3. I was wondering wether the composition is well defined, since I'm unable to prove it directly.

Comment: Ah, I see......

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble pinning down what you're asking. Is the question whether the composition is well-defined in $S^{-1}\mathcal C$ if $S$ satisfies LMS1-2 but not LMS3?

Comment: @KevinArlin Yes, exactly this.